# Snap.SVG how to stop all animations

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I want to find a way of stopping all animations on all rectangle elements within the SVG when a certain element is clicked. 
I'm trying to use something like this:

```
svg.select("rect").stop();
```

but I can't get that to work

Comment: Perhaps if you place all your rectangles in a group `g` and use `stop()` on the group it might work.

Comment: Just checked the [Snap SVG Reference](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.stop). The method `stop()` stops all animations for the *current* element. Not sure if it would work for *nested* elements like I suggested (you could try though). A better solution might be writing a `stopAll()` function to call `stop()` on all your rectangles.

Answer (score 6):

Select all elements of a certain type and then run a `forEach`, passing in a function that takes each individual element.

```
svg.selectAll("rect").forEach(function(elem){elem.stop();});
```